# how to calculate the capacitance for variable power supply 0-20v

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

I am trying to make a variable power supply of 0-20 V; as we all know it uses a step down transformer, bridge circuit, then capacitors and LM317 regulator 
But I want to know how the value of capacitance is calculated
i think i can be calculated from V(rip)=V(rec)/(freq*R*C) but i don't know how can i get the  value of R 
i have source of 220 rms ,50 HZ .what are the calculations ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [making a power supply 0-20v](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162983/making-a-power-supply-0-20v)

Comment: There is a reason why your other question was closed. Have you considered why it was? Do you think this question fixes any of those issues?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum capacitance you need after the full wave bridge is dictated by the maximum droop you can tolerate at whatever your maximum output current spec is.

Your input power is apparently 50 Hz.  The cap will get charged at both peaks of the line cycle, so at 100 Hz rate, or every 10 ms.  Make the simplifying assumption that the capacitor gets charged instantly to the peak voltage every 10 ms.

The change of voltage on a capacitor is:

V = A s / F

Where V is the change in voltage, A the current in amps, s the time in seconds, and F the capacitance in Farads.  To get the capacitance for a certain voltage change at a certain current, rearrange the above to:

F = A s / V

For example, let's say your maximum current is 1 A and that you can tolerate 2 V of droop on the capacitor between line cycle peaks:

(1 A)(10 ms)/(2 V) = 5 mF

That's a pretty big cap, but is in the range you have to expect for this type of primitive power supply.  Note that the more droop you can tolerate, the less capacitance you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult to understand, but if it boils down to:

> "I want to know how the value of capacitance is calculated"

and assuming you're talking about the reservoir capacitor, its capacitance is calculated like this:

$$ C=\frac{I\ dt}{d v}$$

Where C is the capacitance in Farads,

I is the load current, in amperes,

dt is the reciprocal of the ripple frequency, in seconds,

and dV is the allowable ripple voltage across the cap, in volts.